# StudentGPA.java:5: error: '.class' expected error

Tags: java, methods

I keep getting this error when I try to call the other method. I am trying to use method overloads because it requires it.
I know the calculations are right I just want to get the final gpa value to print out the messages based on their value.

Please help me because I understand how to use multiple methods I just want to call the method GPA Calculator and put it in the Main method

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StudentGPA {

public static void main(String[] args){
    gpaCalculator(double gpa);
    double gpa;

    if (gpa == 4.0){
        System.out.println("Excellent! Congratulations on a great job!");
    }

    else if ((gpa >= 3.5)&&(gpa < 4.0)){
        System.out.println("Great job! Keep up the good work!");
    }

    else if ((gpa >= 3.0)&&(gpa <3.5)){
        System.out.println("Very good job! Make sure you keep it this way(or higher) to easily get to graduate school");
    }

    else if ((gpa >= 2.0)&&(gpa <3.0)){
        System.out.println("Time to put a little more effort not to fall below 2.0 and most importantly to get back to 3.0");
    }
    else if (gpa < 2.0){
        System.out.println("I'm sure you'll get back on track, but please make an appointment with an advisor!");
    }
    else{
        return;
    }


}
public static void gpaCalculator(double gpa){

 String grade = "";
 double credit1;
 double credit2;
 double credit3;
 double credit4;
 double gradeValue=0;
 double totPtsClass1=0;
 double totPtsClass2=0;
 double totPtsClass3=0;
 double totPtsClass4=0;
 double totPts=0;
 double totalCredits= 0;


 Scanner scrn = new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.println("Please enter the number of credits of the class 1     (A number)");
  credit1 = scrn.nextDouble();
  System.out.println("Please enter your grades for the class 1(Capital  letters such as A,B+, C-)");
  grade = scrn.next();

  if (grade.equals ("A"))
    gradeValue= 4.00;
  else if (grade.equals("A-"))
    gradeValue= 3.67;
  else if (grade.equals("B+"))
    gradeValue = 3.33;
  else if (grade.equals("B"))
    gradeValue = 3.00;
  else if (grade.equals ("B-"))
    gradeValue = 2.67;
  else if (grade.equals("C+"))
    gradeValue = 2.33;
  else if (grade.equals("C"))
    gradeValue = 2.00;
  else if (grade.equals ("D+"))
    gradeValue = 1.33;
  else if (grade.equals ("D"))
    gradeValue = 1.00;
  else if (grade.equals ("F"))
    gradeValue = 0;
  else if (grade.equals ("FX"))
    gradeValue = 0;
  else
    System.out.println ("Invalid Grade");

  totPtsClass1 = gradeValue * credit1;

  System.out.println("Please enter the number of credits of the class 2 (A number)");
  credit2 = scrn.nextDouble();
  System.out.println("Please enter your grades for the class 2 (Capital letters such as A,B+, C-)");
  grade = scrn.next();

  if (grade.equals ("A"))
    gradeValue= 4.00;
  else if (grade.equals("A-"))
    gradeValue= 3.67;
  else if (grade.equals("B+"))
    gradeValue = 3.33;
  else if (grade.equals("B"))
    gradeValue = 3.00;
  else if (grade.equals ("B-"))
    gradeValue = 2.67;
  else if (grade.equals("C+"))
    gradeValue = 2.33;
  else if (grade.equals("C"))
    gradeValue = 2.00;
  else if (grade.equals ("D+"))
    gradeValue = 1.33;
  else if (grade.equals ("D"))
    gradeValue = 1.00;
  else if (grade.equals ("F"))
    gradeValue = 0;
  else if (grade.equals ("FX"))
    gradeValue = 0;
  else
  System.out.println ("Invalid Grade");

  totPtsClass2 = gradeValue * credit2;

  System.out.println("Please enter the number of credits of the class 3 (A number)");
  credit3 = scrn.nextDouble();
  System.out.println("Please enter your grades for the class 3 (Capital letters such as A,B+, C-)");
  grade = scrn.next();

  if (grade.equals ("A"))
    gradeValue= 4.00;
  else if (grade.equals("A-"))
    gradeValue= 3.67;
  else if (grade.equals("B+"))
    gradeValue = 3.33;
  else if (grade.equals("B"))
    gradeValue = 3.00;
  else if (grade.equals ("B-"))
    gradeValue = 2.67;
  else if (grade.equals("C+"))
    gradeValue = 2.33;
  else if (grade.equals("C"))
    gradeValue = 2.00;
  else if (grade.equals ("D+"))
    gradeValue = 1.33;
  else if (grade.equals ("D"))
    gradeValue = 1.00;
  else if (grade.equals ("F"))
    gradeValue = 0;
  else if (grade.equals ("FX"))
    gradeValue = 0;
  else
    System.out.println ("Invalid Grade");

    totPtsClass3 = gradeValue * credit3;

  System.out.println("Please enter the number of credits of the class 4 (A number)");
  credit4 = scrn.nextDouble();
  System.out.println("Please enter your grades for the class 4 (Capital letters such as A,B+, C-)");
  grade = scrn.next();

  if (grade.equals ("A"))
    gradeValue= 4.00;
  else if (grade.equals("A-"))
    gradeValue= 3.67;
  else if (grade.equals("B+"))
    gradeValue = 3.33;
  else if (grade.equals("B"))
    gradeValue = 3.00;
  else if (grade.equals ("B-"))
    gradeValue = 2.67;
  else if (grade.equals("C+"))
    gradeValue = 2.33;
  else if (grade.equals("C"))
    gradeValue = 2.00;
  else if (grade.equals ("D+"))
    gradeValue = 1.33;
  else if (grade.equals ("D"))
    gradeValue = 1.00;
  else if (grade.equals ("F"))
    gradeValue = 0;
  else if (grade.equals ("FX"))
     gradeValue = 0;
  else
   System.out.println ("Invalid Grade");
  totPtsClass4 = gradeValue * credit4;

  totPts= totPtsClass1+totPtsClass2+totPtsClass3+totPtsClass4;
  totalCredits = credit1+credit2+credit3+credit4;
  gpa= totPts / totalCredits;

  return gpa;
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful for us (who have never seen your code before) if you could include just enough so we can reproduce your problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm sorry, but the main purpose is to print out the message based on the student's gpa. I have to use multiple methods

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of syntax errors, let's start by fixing the method. This

```
public static void gpaCalculator(double gpa){
```

should be

```
public static double gpaCalculator(){
```

And then, to call it, change

```
gpaCalculator(double gpa);
double gpa;
```

to

```
double gpa = gpaCalculator();
```